# Get matching items by comparing two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have an array of objects that look like this

```
const input = [ {id : "1" , text: "ABC", value: "abc" }, {id : "2" , text: "DEF", value: "def" },  {id : "3" , text: "LMN", value: "lmn" } ]
```

The above wrapper function when passed respective inputs, should return the following

```
const ids = ["1", "3"]
const values = ["def", "lmn"]
const texts = ["DEF", "LMN"]

getValues(input, ids, "text") // ["ABC", "LMN"]
getValues(input, values, "id") // ["2", "3"]
getValues(input, texts, "value") // ["def", "lmn"]
```

When group of `ids` are passed and when required field is `text` it should return the matching `text` values from the input array. Same goes when `values` and `id` is passed as required fields, it should return all matching `ids` from input

Code I tried

```
function getValues(input1, input2, field){
  const result = input1.map(({id, text, value}) => {
     if(text === input2){
       return input1[field];
     }
  }); 
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Your `getValues()` function is not ideally defined. It has to assume that if the caller passed `"text"` then the filter is implicitly on `"id"`, and vice-versa.

Comment: why not pass the field that needs to compare against as well. for example in first 1 id. something like `getValues(input, {id: ids}, "text")` or `getValues(input, ids, "id","text")`

Comment: @cmgchess could you tell me how that implementation going to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two general purpose functions that filter a list of objects for a given key attribute whose value is in a provided list of `keyvalues`, and then returns the chosen `attr` for those objects.

The second option folds the filter attribute key and value into an object such as `{"id": ids}`.

```js
const input = [ {id : "1" , text: "ABC", value: "abc" }, {id : "2" , text: "DEF", value: "def" },  {id : "3" , text: "LMN", value: "lmn" } ]

const ids = ["1", "3"];
const values = ["def", "lmn"];
const texts = ["DEF", "LMN"];

function getValuesOld(objects, key, keyvalues, attr) {
  return objects.filter(x => keyvalues.includes(x[key])).map(x => x[attr]);
}

console.log(getValuesOld(input, "id", ids, "text"));
console.log(getValuesOld(input, "value", values, "id"));
console.log(getValuesOld(input, "text", texts, "value"));

function getValues(objects, key, attr) {
  const [keyname, keyvalues] = Object.entries(key)[0];
  return objects.filter(x => keyvalues.includes(x[keyname])).map(x => x[attr]);
}

console.log(getValues(input, { "id": ids }, "text"));
console.log(getValues(input, { "value": values }, "id"));
console.log(getValues(input, { "text": texts }, "value"));
```

Comment: can convert keyvalues to a set before if needed but i don't know if it matters much

Comment: Updated to incorporate your modified question and test code.

Comment: @jarod, can we avoid the extra argument and call it this way, `getValues(input, "id": [ids], "text")` , where `text `is the field with which it will be compared to?

Comment: @lrr97  might have to do like this `getValues(input, {"id": ids}, "text")`. and in the function you can do something like `const [field,values] = Object.entries(input2)[0]` now you have all that is needed

Comment: @cmgchess good idea, have added.

Answer (score -1):

const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const array2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

const matchingItems = array1.filter(item => array2.includes(item));

console.log(matchingItems); // Output: [3, 4, 5]

Comment: While this code gives an example of the `.filter()` method, it doesn't show the OP how they can apply it to their specific situation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).